# I want to remove the equality operator and take only right side values

Tags: python-3.x

I want to parse the following string:

```
key_value_line = 'date=2013-03-15 15:59:21,esname=FHY,esid=FG224B3907501199,es_group=N/A,src=192.168.1.133,spt=52906,dst=173.194.39.154,dpt=80,vdom=root,rcv=11257,proto=http,url=googlesyndication.com,sid=62551133,info=URL has been visited,cat=webfilter'
```

The result should contain only the value on the right side of `=`.

This is my try:

```
splited = key_value_line.split('=')
values = []
for v in range(1,len(splited),2):
    values.append(splited[v])
print(values)
```

The result should be:

```
['2013-03-15 15:59:21','FHY','FG224B3907501199','N/A','192.168.1.133',...]
```

But I get

```
['2013-03-15 15:59:21,esname', 'FG224B3907501199,es_group', '192.168.1.133,spt', '173.194.39.154,dpt', 'root,rcv', 'http,url', '62551133,info', 'webfilter']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data are comma-separated.

You should first split your string using the comma as separator, and then the `=` operator.